# Filter based on other filters in Google App Script

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, gs-vlookup, google-sheets-filter-view

I would like to see/view all my contacts based on the same company name, whenever I filter my worksheet.
For example, My table:

[image: my table]

If I choose to filter Contact Name: "Adi" I would like to see this:

[image: Excuted table]

Because Adi and Dan belong to the same Company. another example could be, If I choose to filter 
Last Modified field: " 3/05/2020", The result should be:

[image: Result Table]

Again because Adi and Dan belong to the same Company. The solution could be on app script as well.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Here:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hbKgKwt4x-x_l8TIYkpTNJDb5CFhuWhbQQi34YO89t8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=FILTER(A:C, REGEXMATCH(A:A, VLOOKUP(G1, {B:B, A:A}, 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=A2=VLOOKUP(G$1, {B:B, A:A}, 2, 0)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Can your formula filter the original table? and not show a new table in other columns?

Comment: I don't understand ,after excuted your formula , I can only see company1